# How to play a sound when pressing a specific key

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to play a sound when I hit the <kbd>b</kbd> key, but i cant seem to figure it out

HTML:

```
<audio id="music">
  <source src="asap.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

JS:

```
var s2 = document.getElementById('music')

document).keydown(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 66) {
     s2.play();
        }
});
```

Comment: What is your specific question? What’s going wrong? Is `document)` supposed to be `$(document)`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BrettWilliams/SMRL2/ this will help you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP does not trust his console. It already tells what to do

Answer (score 2):

```js
//to play on the key A do this(using Jquery):
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 66){
  document.getElementById('audio').play();
  }
  
  if(e.keyCode == 65){
  document.getElementById('audio').pause();
  }
});
```

```html
<p>
press the "b" to play 
</p>
<p>
press the "a" to pause 
</p>

<!-- Create an audio element and hide it with css: display:none -->
<audio id="audio" controls style="display:none">
  <source src="http://butlerccwebdev.net/support/html5-video/media/soundfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Why you're using `onclick` for the button but `.addEventListener()` for the keydown event?

Comment: that was just a plus point and a plus thing that you can do that on click of that button too !